# What is 'server' for localdb SQL Server?

Tags: c#, auth0

I'm using Auth0.com for authentification. MVC5 with AngularJS. 
When setting connection with SQL Server database I have to set 'server:' ?

I've already set database username and password but can't figure out what a server should be for localDb.

I've already tried : 
- (localdb)\v11.0
- localdb
- MSSQLLocalDB
- localhost. (refused)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest (localdb) is correct, however it maybe that you are not using the correct instance name for the localdb you've installed.

I recommend using "SqlLocalDB -i" as detailed in the article below.

[SQL Server: How to find all localdb instance names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157191/sql-server-how-to-find-all-localdb-instance-names)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Links have a danger of dying over time - you should provide a quote from the content in the link as part of your answer, that'll increase its value.

Comment: As I'm thinking now. Is it even possible to access localdb not localy?

Comment: @Jacek - The answer about using localdb remotely is no. This is covered in the following question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193746/can-sql-server-express-localdb-be-connected-to-remotely)