# How do I connect to SQL Server 2017 LocalDB?

Tags: visual-studio, localdb, sql-server-2017

I've been using `(localdb)\ProjectsV13` as part of my VS 2017 installation, however, I recently needed to access some SQL Server 2017 features during development, so I installed SQL Server 2017 LocalDB as well (not part of VS installer still unfortunately). Now I have 2016 and 2017 localdb installed side by side:

[image]

How do I connect to this 2017 localdb instance?

Connecting via SSMS, `(localdb)\ProjectsV13` and `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` both still return:

```
SELECT @@VERSION

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 16299: ) (Hypervisor)
```

`(localdb)\ProjectsV14` does not seem to exist (times out when trying to connect).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get a list of all instances of LocalDb from the command prompt with the `SqlLocalDb.exe` program, which is in your PATH by default:

```
sqllocaldb info
```

That will list out the available instances.  From there you can get additional information about a specific instance with:

```
sqllocaldb info <instance name>
```

It will produce output similar to the following:

> Name:               MSSQLLocalDB
>   Version:            13.1.4001.0
>   Shared name:
>   Owner:              DESKTOP-557IFJ5\Bradley Uffner
>   Auto-create:        Yes
>   State:              Stopped
>   Last start time:    12/4/2017 11:42:58 PM
>   Instance pipe name:

You should be able to use this information to connect through SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Hmm. `sqllocaldb info` only shows `MSSQLLocalDB` and `ProjectsV13`, the two I have already tried. Do I have to start some service after installing LocalDB? I can't find one.

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to start anything.  It's possible that you don't have an instance with 2017, in which case you can easily create one from the command line with `sqllocaldb create <name of new instance>`.  This will create an instance with the highest available version, though there are options to use older versions.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

With SSMS, you should be able to connect to 2017 installation with its instance name, user id and password, that you used during installation of SQL Server 2017

or see this post

[SQL Server: How to find all localdb instance names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157191/sql-server-how-to-find-all-localdb-instance-names)

Comment: You do not provide any of that information when installing localdb.

Comment: find out the instance name from services on your computer and then use it